# Open iframe content in new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

I want to open iframe in new window instead of print, I tried but can't get it 
working

**EDIT** Just wanted to open new window and view the structure as my page is having dynamic data and wanted to style for print.

```
$('.btn-prnt').on("click", function(e){
    var divElements = $(".contentWrap").html();
    var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;
    var iframe = $('<iframe class="hidden" id="printer"></iframe>').appendTo('body');
    var printer = $('#printer');
    printer.contents().find('body').append("<html><head><title>Print Title</title><style></style></head><body><table width='670'><tr><td colspan='2'>" + divElements + "</td></tr></table></body>");
    printer.get(0).contentWindow.print();
    printer.remove();
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do @SanjeevKumar. If you want the content in a different window, why are you using an `iframe` in the first place?

Comment: @AngelPolitis I am trying to style the page differently for print and I just wanted to get the html code of the page so I could write css and thats why I wanted to preview first before print. since my page is dynamic, not able to get the source of the page. Not sure why get downvoted.

Comment: Check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48739977/open-iframe-content-in-new-window/48740273#48740273) @SanjeevKumar. It's pretty generic but it should give you an idea on how to write content into the new window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic solution to your problem consists of the following two steps:

1. To open a new window, you can use [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open).
2. To write the `HTML` content to the new window's document, fetch it and use [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write).

**Code:**

```js
$('.btn-prnt').on("click", function(e) {
  var
    /* Create a new window. */
    newWin = window.open(),

    /* The html you want to write in the new window. */
    html = "<html>...</html>";

  /* Get the window's document and write the html content. */
  newWin.document.write(html);
});
```

Comment: This is showing error, I tried this already, in the new window I am just getting `[object Object]`

Comment: You're welcome @SanjeevKumar. I'm glad I could help 